# bookmark to open pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I want to have a bookmark in Chrome to open pgAdmin 4. The only problem is, it seems like every time pgAdmin 4 itself launches, it chooses a different port (normally this is not a problem because it opens a tab for you straightaway, but if I can't find the tab I want to just open a new one).

Are there any hacks you can think of to make a bookmark that somehow finds the right port? Failing that, how can I easily figure out what port it's running at, so I can manually modify the URL accordingly? I'm on a Mac.

Just reopening pgAdmin the program doesn't work, because it seems that if it's already open in one tab it doesn't want to open another tab.

Answer (score 3):

By default pgAdmin 4 is using a ephemeral port (49152 to 65535), which is assigned by your os. If you want to have pgAdmin using the same port every time the application launches, you can change the following line of pgAdmin's configuration file (config_local.py in your pgAdmin4 installation folder): `DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = <port>`

Example: `DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 12345`

Make sure that you use a available/unused port.

After changing and saving the configuration, restart pgAdmin and create a bookmark with the selected port (e.g. `http://localhost:12345/browser`).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I'm using a Mac and I can't find a config_local.py in either the PostgreSQL 11 folder created in Applications or in ~/.pgadmin. From searching around I think I'm supposed to create one if it doesn't exist, but can you tell me where I should create it? Or is there some place I haven't looked yet where I should look?

Comment: The file is neither in the postgresql installation folder nor in your home directory. The file should be in the installation folder of pgAdmin4. There should already be a file called `config.py`. If the file `config_local.py` does not exist, just create it.

Comment: Just saw that the default installation folder on linux is `/var/lib/pgadmin4/`. Maybe it's the same on mac.

Comment: I found it by searching for config.py instead (just deleted my other comment): `/Library/PostgreSQL/11/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/config.py`

Comment: After doing that, killing PgAdmin 4 using Activity Monitor, and starting it up again, it still got launched at a different port unfortunately. I had gone with 12345 and I got 64299

Comment: And also I see that in config.py, I already had `DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 5050` (this would have been added by the installation itself, I never added that) but clearly that wasn't being used. So maybe there's just a PgAdmin bug where this setting is being ignored.

Comment: Above answer works when you run pgAdmin4 in Web mode but if you are running in Desktop mode I have provided solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on pgAdmin4 icon in your taskbar -> select `configure` option, there you will find below option as shown in screenshot, provide the port you want to and save & restart, Now you can bookmark pagadmin4 url :)

[image]

[image]
Hope that helps.